# Privacy approach for a light-weight wallet

Tags: privacy, spv, pruning

I am looking for an approach to build a privacy centric lighter weight wallet.
By privacy centric I only mean: network observers should be unable to guess the addresses belongs to the same wallet.
So querying information about addresses should be private.
By light-weight I mean:
1. Do not store hundreds of GB of data (a few is fine).
2. Do not sync for ages. Should be finished within an hour maybe.
The lightest privacy preserving approach I was able to find is pruning, what solves my first criteria, but not the second.
BIP37 is not a good. (See: https://jonasnick.github.io/blog/2015/02/12/privacy-in-bitcoinj/)
Do you guys have suggestions? (Or direct me to a better room to ask this question?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I conducted an extensive research](https://medium.com/@nopara73/bitcoin-privacy-landscape-in-2017-zero-to-hero-guidelines-and-research-a10d30f1e034) on the topic and to date the lightest weight wallet, that is resistant against network analisys is a **full-SPV wallet**.
The structure of it is evident and some are already working on it, including me. This wallet would basically sync the headers and only download blocks from the creation of the wallet, and would store them in a pruned manner.